# How to include script library on CI controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Here is my sample code:

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/base_header');
    $this->load->view('templates/login');
    $this->load->view('templates/base_footer_JS');

    echo "<script src='".base_url()."/lib/scripts/login.js'></script>";
}
```

JavaScript is working but jQuery does not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has a javascript class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

You would load the jquery library through:

```
$this->load->library('jquery');
```

Then you can paste this into your head section of your view:

```
<?php echo $library_src;?>
<?php echo $script_head;?>
```

For additional javascript files, I typically create a resource folder in my application folder, then use the base_url function to link to the files like:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('resources/name-of-js-file.js');?>" type="text/javascript"
```